# How to check if a given String is a composite format String

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm writing a function that does [composite formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is vb.net, but it would be the same for C#, I guess. I want to check, if `message` is a composite formatting string, because if it is not, I could make a different output for the rest of the parameters.

```
    public sub write(message as String, paramarray paramlist() as Object)
        if paramlist.Length = 0 then
            writeString(message)
        else
            if isCompositeFormatString(message) then
                writeString(String.Format(message, paramlist))
            else
                ' ... make different output for paramlist
            end if
        end if
    end sub
```

I see two ways to check this:

1) make a RegEx that looks for {...} strings

2) try `String.Format` and catch `FormatException` to handle this case

The question is, is there already a function that recognizes composite format strings in .net?

Comment: why noy use String.Format ?

Comment: I happen to have written something that does this: https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/develop/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/Diagnostics/Strings/PlaceholderHelpers.cs It is used in a few Roslyn analyzers: https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/tree/develop/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/Diagnostics/Strings But no, there is no built-in function that verifies if something is a string with placeholders. I went with the Regex approach

Comment: why not search for "{0}" Since you are only using one element if it doesn't have it, won't work

Comment: @lordkain: I am already using String.Format for the task, but the thing is I want to decide IF I want to use String.Format or not.

Comment: @Claudius What about `{1}` or `{26}`? Or how about with formatting like `{0:C}`? It get pretty complicated, pretty fast.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but how about `string.Format(input, "SomeCrazyString").Contains("SomeCrazyString");`? (assumes you always have a `{0..}`

Comment: @DavidG Format above only have single composition. plus OP wants to test if "message" has composite format, not if it is correct. Most situations when using composite formating will have {0}

Comment: @Claudius "most situations" is of no use to anyone.

Comment: Why not just format it and see if it has changed? `message == string.Format(message, args)`

Comment: @DavidG for the situation presented here works 100% of the time.

Comment: @Claudius Show me where OP says they don't have any format specifiers?

Comment: @Claudius: No, I didn't say we have only simple formatting. "Most situations" might apply, but is not a viable solution.

Comment: @DavidG: "{0:C}" is exactly my point, because a RegEx looks easy, but can get complicated pretty fast. in vb.net, we also have double escaping, so "{{0}}" would NOT be a formatting string, because the braces are escaped.

Comment: @gpinkas What about my potential solution above, would that work for you?

Comment: @gpinkas that clarify things. It then depends how tricky you need to be. with regex you could get composite numbers to check against number of variable for given format?

Comment: @DavidG Please post it as an answer, since it gets lost in the comments.

Comment: @gpinkas my regex solution accounts for format specifiers, escaped formatting placeholders and nested brackets.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This looks like the best way. Could you please post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: This is a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598130/how-to-check-if-a-given-string-is-a-composite-format-string#comment60793147_36598130) from @JeroenVannevel, I only reformat it to mark this as the answer.

I happen to have written something that does this: 
[github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/develop/VSDiagnostics/](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/blob/develop/VSDiagnostics/)…

It is used in a few Roslyn analyzers: [github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/tree/develop/VSDiagnostics/](https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/tree/develop/VSDiagnostics/)…

But no, there is no built-in function that verifies if something is a string with placeholders. I went with the Regex approach